# Is this instance of B a property of an instance of A?

Tags: c#, oop

Take a look at this scenario:

```
//base class
abstract class AAA { } 

//class 1
class BBB : AAA
{
     //Field of ZZZ type
     public ZZZ ZField = new ZZZ();
}

//class 2
class ZZZ
{
      public string foo() { return ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass ? "yes" : "no"; }

      bool ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass 
      {
          get { /* here */ }
      }
}

//running test
new BBB().ZField.foo(); // => expected "yes"
new ZField.foo(); // => expected "no"
```

My question is:

Is there an way to implement `ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass`?

Comment: `new ZField.foo();` I am pretty sure there is a mistake here.

Comment: It is not possible, but why do you need it? If you provide your actual problem, it might be solvable in a different way.

Comment: yes, it's new ZZZ().foo();

Comment: I need to know (in BBB instance) if any field was modified, but I don't want to add a event (for exemple) to each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It won;t be possible in a straight forward way. Since ZZZ has not direct relation with AAA. One possible way is to have a public Object exposed from ZZZ and pass the BBB ref to it and then check for that:

```
public class ZZZ
{
  public string foo() { return ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass ? "yes" : "no"; }

  bool ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass 
  {
      get { return TestForAAA is AAA; }
  }

  public object TestForAAA { get; set; }
}
```

And while using this would pass BBB's ref to the object.

of course this adds dependency but works!

Comment: Yes, I will have to do something like this. I was finding in reflection, stacktrace but no way until now.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. You can't really do that. First, instances of types can never know *a priori* what variables or fields are referencing them, so you can't be certain that any `BBB.ZField` points to the current `ZZZ` instance.

The closest you can get is something like this:

```
public class ZZZ
{
    public string foo() { return ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass ? "yes" : "no"; }
    protected bool virtual ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass 
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}

class BBB : AAA
{
    //Field of ZZZ type
    public readonly ZZZ ZField = new BBB_ZZZ();

    private class BBB_ZZZ : ZZZ
    {
        protected override bool ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass 
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
}


new BBB().ZField.foo(); // "yes"
new ZZZ().foo();        // "no"
```

Notice I've made the field `readonly`, this means that it can never be reassigned later. That will ensure that `ZField` is not set to an instance of `ZZZ` for which `foo` will return `"no"`.

Of course, there's nothing stopping you (or someone else) from implementing a separate subclass which will violate these semantics:

```
private class Fake_ZZZ : ZZZ
{
    protected override bool ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass 
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}

new Fake_ZZZ().foo();   // "yes"
```

In any case, these semantics are clumsy and awkward. Whatever it is you're trying to accomplish with this, there's got to be a better way to go about it. I'd recommend you rethink your solution altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle the need to know the container of the `ZZZ` instance is to inject it into the constructor of the `ZZZ`.

```
 public class ZZZ
 { 
     public ZZZ(object owner = null)
     { 
       this.owner = owner;
     }
     readonly object owner;

     public bool ImAPropertyOfAnAAADerivedClass 
     {
         get { return owner is AAA; }
     }
 }
```

Then, to make this work with your containing class, change the `BBB` definition to:

```
 public class BBB : AAA
 {
     public BBB(){ 
        ZField = new ZZZ(this);
     }
     public readonly ZZZ ZField;
 }
```

This pattern is a very simple example of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) that will give you the results you are looking for.